# Trying to add new elements into XML using XML to LINQ in the right sort order

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am trying to add some entries to a XML file:

```
foreach(var talkNumber in listNumbers)
{
       var newElem = new XElement("PublicTalk",
                               new XAttribute("Number", talkNumber),
                               new XAttribute("Excluded", false),
                               new XAttribute("ExcludedFromDate", "1900-01-01"),
                               new XAttribute("Note", ""),
                               new XAttribute("TimesHeard", 0),
                               new XAttribute("LastHeard", "1900-01-01")
                              );
       ptLangInfo.Add(newElem);
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PublicTalkTitles>
  <!-- English -->
  <eng>
    <PublicTalk Number="21" Excluded="false" ExcludedFromDate="1900-01-01" Note="" TimesHeard="1" LastHeard="2023-10-15" />
    <PublicTalk Number="1" Excluded="false" ExcludedFromDate="1900-01-01" Note="" TimesHeard="0" LastHeard="1900-01-01" />
    <PublicTalk Number="2" Excluded="false" ExcludedFromDate="1900-01-01" Note="" TimesHeard="0" LastHeard="1900-01-01" />
    <PublicTalk Number="3" Excluded="false" ExcludedFromDate="1900-01-01" Note="" TimesHeard="0" LastHeard="1900-01-01" />
  </eng>
</PublicTalkTitles>
```

The problem as you can see is that I want to add these new items in the correct numerical order to the existing ones. They get added to the bottom.

In my code snippet `ptLangInfo` is the `eng` element.

Comment: Are the `talkNumber` values already sorted?  And are the `<eng><PublicTalk Number="21" ...>` elements also already sorted?

Comment: @dbc At this point in time I am going to say "yes" to both of those questions.

Comment: Have you tried `foreach(var talkNumber in listNumbers.Reverse())`?

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I don't see how that helps because they still need to be inserted into the right place in `ptLangInfo` so that my resulting list is from 1 upwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [`XContainer.Elements()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.elements?view=net-7.0) returns an `IEnumerable<XElement>` not an `IList<XElement>`.  As such there's no builtin `log(n)` way to insert an element into the enumeration of child elements using a binary search and assuming it's already sorted.

Thus I'd recommend just sorting them afterwards:

```
// Order the elements by the Number attribute
var ordered = ptLangInfo.Elements("PublicTalk")
    .OrderBy(e => (int?)e.Attribute("Number"))
    .ToList();
// Remove the elements from ptLangInfo using System.Xml.Linq.Extensions.Remove()
ordered.Remove(); 
// Add them back in the new order
ptLangInfo.Add(ordered);
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DePzR5).

Comment: OK, but why do you remove from ordered and then add the empty list? Typo? I don't understand that bit.

Comment: Not a typo. It's an extension method in the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace: [`System.Xml.Linq.Extensions.Remove<T>(IEnumerable<T>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.extensions.remove?view=net-7.0#system-xml-linq-extensions-remove-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0)))) which removes the elements from their current parent.  It's needed so they can be re-added. Please see the fiddle, which does work.

Comment: OK, so `ordered.Remove();` is similar to saying `ptLangInfo.Elements("PublicTalk").Remove();` (or whatever the right syntax would be. Either way, I confirm your code works and thanks for the fiddle which gave it context. +1

Comment: @AndrewTruckle = exactly.  It might be clearer to make a list of the current elements, remove the list from ptLangInfo, add the new elements to the list, sort the list, then add the list to ptLangInfo.  But people seem to prefer briefer answers here, so that's what I wrote.

Comment: Learn something new there! Beyond what I asked. 